# Is it possible to tell Mathematica that a user defined function is continuous?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, assumptions

If I use an arbitrary function `f'[t]` inside a definite integral, Mathematica (correctly) refuses to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, because it doesn't know if `f'[t]` is continuous.

Is there a way to define an arbitrary function with the assumption that it is continuous, such that the definite integral between a and b evaluates to `f[b] - f[a]`?

Comment: The simplest approach from the linked question is to use `SetAttributes[f, NumericFunction]` and then integrate.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks!

Comment: @CarlWoll That seems like a rather inappropriate `Attribute` to set to make `Integrate` apply the fundamental theorem.  Do you know why it was designed like this?